# expand data frame by a specified times series in R

Tags: r

I want to expand my data by a time series for every `ID`, `OCC` and `DOSE` available in my `dfin`.

```
times <- c(2,4)

dfin <-
ID  OCC  DOSE
1    1    0.1
1    2    0.2
2    1    0.1


dfout <- 
ID  OCC  DOSE  TIME
1    1    0.1   2
1    1    0.1   4
1    2    0.2   2
1    2    0.2   4
2    1    0.1   2
2    1    0.1   4
```

how can i do this in RStudio?

Comment: yep. Got it thanks!

Comment: try `transform(dfin[rep(seq_len(nrow(dfin)), each = 2),], TIMEs = times)`